# No value accessor for form control with name: 'period'

Tags: angular

I am implementing a date range picker, so basically 2 input but controlled by the same component.

I am doing the following =>

Form.component.ts

```
  initForm(): void {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      period: ['', [Validators.required]],
    })
  }
```

Form.component.html

```
              <app-data-range-picker
                [label]="'FIELDS.CAMPAIGN_PERIOD.NAME' | translate"
                [formControlName]="'period'"
                [isRequired]="true"
              >
              </app-data-range-picker>
```

app-data-range-picker.ts

```
export class DataRangePickerComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
  @Output() valueChange = new EventEmitter<DateRangeFilter>()

  @Input() label: string
  @Input() isRequired = false
  @Input() isInvalid = false
  @Input() isValid = false
  @Input() disabled = false
  @Input() readonly = false
  @Input() value: DateRangeFilter

  onChange = (_: DateRangeFilter) => {}
  onTouched = () => {}

  writeValue(value: DateRangeFilter) {
    this.value = value
    this.onChange(this.value)
    this.valueChange.emit(value)
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: (value: DateRangeFilter) => void): void {
    this.onChange = fn
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any) {
    this.onTouched = fn
  }

  setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean) {
    this.disabled = isDisabled
  }

  setValue(key: string, value: string) {
    this.writeValue({
      ...this.value,
      [key]: value,
    })
  }
}
```

app-date-range-picker.html

```
<div class="d-flex flex-column input-group">
  <label *ngIf="label" [ngClass]="{ required: isRequired, 'mb-1 text-s': true }">{{ label }}</label>
  <div class="d-inline-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <app-date-picker
      [isInvalid]="isInvalid"
      [isValid]="isValid"
      [readonly]="readonly"
      [disabled]="disabled"
      (dateChange)="setValue('from', $event)"
    ></app-date-picker>

    <svg-icon class="mx-2" src="assets/svg/separator.svg"></svg-icon>

    <app-date-picker
      [isInvalid]="isInvalid"
      [isValid]="isValid"
      [readonly]="readonly"
      [disabled]="disabled"
      (dateChange)="setValue('to', $event)"
    ></app-date-picker>
  </div>
</div>
```

It should be ok., but I get the error

> Cannot find control with name: 'period'

I imported ReactiveFormModule and FormModule in the modules. my other custom input work fine but not this one

EDIT : If I add `ngDefaultControl` it doesn't trigger error, but it my custom input don7t work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason and I am ****

I forgot

```
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => DataRangePickerComponent),
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not providing NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR. When you extend the ControlValueAccessor you either need to provide the NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR with the current class in the component decorator with

```
providers: [{ provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, useExisting: DataRangePickerComponent }]
```

or you inject the NgControl into the component and assign the current instance to the valueAccessor.

```
constructor(@Self() @Optional() ngControl: NgControl) {
  ngControl.valueAccessor = this;
}
```